# Writing the return function

Tags: python, return

This is my code:

```
def issorted(numlist):
    sortbool = True
    for i in range(1, len(numlist)):
        if numlist[i] < numlist[i-1]:
            sortbool = False
            if True:
              return(not sortbool)
    return(sortbool)
```

How do I put at least one more return statement? This is so that it can abort the function prematurely when a local violation of the sort-order requirement is detected.

The example of the output given are:

```
>>> print(issorted([3, 4, 5.0, 7]))
True
>>> print(issorted([-1, 8, -3, 8]))
False
>>> print(issorted([1]))
True
>>> print(issorted([]))
True
```

Comment: `if True:` is *always* true. Since you set `sortbool` too `False` and return `not sortbool` (so `True`) your whole `if numlist[i] < numlist[i-1]:` block could be replaced with `return True` with no loss of functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your variables sparingly. Sometimes they are useful, sometimes they confuse you.

```
def issorted(numlist):
    for i in range(1, len(numlist)):
        if numlist[i] < numlist[i-1]:
            #you want to return False and exit the function.
            #return is the best option here.
            return False
    #if the for loop succeeds, you want to return True by default
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return a constant; there is no need for a variable here and you got thoroughly confused. Your code:

```
if numlist[i] < numlist[i-1]:
    sortbool = False
    if True:
        return(not sortbool)
```

ends up returning `True`, always, because you set `sortbool` to `False`, but return `not sortbool` (so not `False`, which is `True`), the the `True` value is true, which it *always* is.

Your code should return `False` as soon as you find a position in the list where the value is smaller than the preceding value, otherwise return `True`; just hard-code those values as literals:

```
def issorted(numlist):
    previous = numlist[0]
    for value in numlist:
        if value < previous:
            # the current value is smaller than the previous,
            # so the list is not (forward) sorted. Exit with False
            return False
        previous = value
    # all values were equal or larger than their predecessors, so 
    # the list is sorted, exit with True
    return True
```

Note that I pulled a little trick there; I use an extra variable to track the previous value instead of generating an index.